# what exactly is "call"/"apply" doing here?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
     each: function( object, callback, args ) {
   ...
          if ( callback.apply( object[ name ], args ) === false ) {
            break;
          }
 ...
          if ( callback.call( object[ i ], i, object[ i++ ] ) === false ) {
            break;
          }


    return object;
  }
```

you can ignore the code maybe .. its jQuery.each implementation from jQuery

i wanted to know what does this line do 
`callback.apply( object[ name ], args ) === false` or `callback.call( object[ name ], name, object[ name ] ) === false`

I mean what all conditions does these construct try to check?

Comment: Have you done any research? `call` and `apply` don't do any checking of conditions. They call functions. They're in the spec, of course ([here](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-function.prototype.call) and [here](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-function.prototype.apply)), and MDN covers them [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply).

Answer (score 1):

`callback.apply( object[ name ], args )` is simply calling function `callback` with `object[name]` as context (`this`) and `args` as arguments. jQuery provides a way to break a loop by returning `false`, as stated in [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/):

> We can break the `$.each()` loop at a particular iteration by making the callback function return `false`. Returning non-false is the same as a `continue` statement in a for loop; it will skip immediately to the next iteration.

So, this piece of code:

```
if ( callback.apply( object[ name ], args ) === false ) {
  break;
}
```

checks if the function returns `false`, and if yes, breaks the loop.

---

If we skip the context part, the code could look like this (in ES6):

```
if (callback(...args) === false) {
  break;
}
```

Comment: ah thanks .. yes i have basic understanding of how call and apply work.. so i reached the point what you seem to be telling.. but is this just a jquery thing?? like if callback is just `return x`  and if I do each on an array like [true,false,true,false] .. it runs over complete array and dont break at first `false`

Comment: ok so I looked into `.each` .. so what it means is .. this `call` thing equal to `false` is just a feature given to us by `jQuery.each` to break in between and is no  javascript trickery .. will I be correct to say that ?